# ExecWait and MySQL with Parameters Not Working

Tags: mysql, nsis

If I run this from a command prompt it works:

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\bin>MySQL.exe -u root -p --password=xyz --port=3322 --protocol=TCP < "C:\temp folder\CREATE_database.sql"
```

So I know the .sql script is fine.

But in my NSIS script I see a command prompt window pop up but disappear quickly and the database isn't created:

```
  ExecWait '"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p --password=root --port=3322 --protocol=TCP < "C:\temp folder\CREATE_database.sql"'
```

Am I not passing in the parameters to MySQL.exe properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecWait` just creates a simple process, it does not support stdin/stdout redirection.

You can use cmd.exe as a helper:

```
Section 
nsExec::ExectoStack 'cmd.exe /c if 1==1 "c:\path\to\myapp.exe" -param1 -param2 < "stdin file.txt"'
pop $0
pop $1
DetailPrint "Exit code=$0"
DetailPrint "Output=|$1|"
SectionEnd
```

or you can use the [ExecDos plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ExecDos_plug-in).